# Error plotting serially incoming data. The graph is displayed but nothing is plotted

Tags: python, numpy

My serial data read from microcontroller is something like this

> 34,45,55
> 33,46,56

My code is:

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import serial as sr

#------global variables
data = np.array([])
cond = False

#-----plot data-----
def plot_data():
    global cond, data
    
    if (cond == True):
        
        a = s.readline()
        a.decode()
        
        if(len(data) < 100):
            data = np.append(data,float(a[0:4]))
        else:
            data[0:99] = data[1:100]
            data[99] = float(a[0:4])
        
        lines.set_xdata(np.arange(0,len(data)))
        lines.set_ydata(data)
        
        canvas.draw()
    
    root.after(1,plot_data)

def plot_start():
    global cond
    cond = True
    s.reset_input_buffer()

def plot_stop():
    global cond
    cond = False
    

#-----Main GUI code-----
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Real Time Plot')
root.configure(background = 'light blue')
root.geometry("700x500") # set the window size

#------create Plot object on GUI----------
# add figure canvas
fig = Figure();
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,100),ylim=(0, 120)); #displaying only 100 samples

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5,6)
lines = ax.plot([],[])[0]

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 10,y=10, width = 500,height = 400)
canvas.draw()
#----start serial port----
s = sr.Serial('COM5',9600);
s.reset_input_buffer()



root.after(1,plot_data)
root.mainloop()
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 804, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-10-0f59d768080a>", line 21, in plot_data
    data = np.append(data,float(a[0:4]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'51,6'
```

Comment: You should replace the , by a . like this : "51.6".replace(",",".") because the comma is not recognize for casting to float

Comment: @LCMa I put a=a.replace("," , ".") after decode,now the error says:  Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 804, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-11-92b60f8a8cde>", line 20, in plot_data
    a=a.replace(",",".")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'